# Stripe over Xamarin Forms UWP

Tags: xamarin, uwp, stripe-payments

I would like to know if it's possible to implement `Stripe` payments over UWP? Because I'm not able to find anything about it  and I need it over each platforms *Android, iOS, UWP*.

Thank for any help !

Answer (score 1):

Stripe has an [official .NET API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/dotnet)

Comment: Hi ! Thank you, but how can I implement it next to? I mean I already have `Xamarin Stripe` which works over Android & iOS. So  how can I make it work on UWP without breaking the Android/iOS part that work diffently?